# Safari on Retina display is not rendering properly google maps

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, joomla, safari

Link to my dev site: http://devel.cms-start.com/maissen-architekten/immobilien 
There are 2 google maps generated on this page. 
Google map blocks look fine in all browsers/platforms except Safari/iOS.[image]

As you can see at this image google maps rendering is broken.

Comment: Update 1: Google map also looks broken at iMac and latest Macbook Pro / Safari. In all other browsers it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch on google, there is a section Maps for mobile Help
https://support.google.com/gmm/?hl=en